# CSS - image before alignment problems

Tags: css

Hi all I have an h2 element like so:

```
<h2 id="back">Back</h2>
```

and I added an image before:

```
#back::before {
    background-image: url(/images/arrow.png);
    background-size: 20px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    content: "";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

However the output is the screenshot attached...my question is how do I get my arrow to be aligned in the middle and before the text. How would I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this with flex:

```
#back{
display: flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
....
}
#back::before{
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
rest of your styling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#back::before {
    background-image: url(/images/arrow.png);
    background-size: 20px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    content: "";
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**Try vertical align property.**

Comment: I dont see vertial align in your code....unless I am blind

Comment: oops, now you see right there.